# Como consigo ser admin, pq tecnicamente eu ja sou do meu PC k mas aparentemente n pra o SQL DEVELOPER LKLL:

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

```sql
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO ****;
grant all to ****;
```

```
ORA-01932: a opção ADMIN não foi concedida para a atribuição 'CONNECT'
01932. 00000 -  "ADMIN option not granted for role '%s'"
*Cause:    The operation requires the admin option on the role.
*Action:   Obtain the grant option and re-try.
```

Comment: Está conectado como o que ? Tentou < grant all privilegies > to ... ? https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljgrant.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parece que você está se referindo a problemas de autenticação ou acesso no SQL Developer ou em algum sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados. Se você deseja se autenticar como administrador (ou superusuário) em um sistema, como o SQL Developer, siga estas etapas gerais:

1. **Autenticação Inicial**: Verifique se você está usando as credenciais corretas para se autenticar. Isso normalmente inclui um nome de usuário e senha. Se você estiver tentando acessar como administrador, pode ser necessário fornecer credenciais de administrador.
2. **Credenciais de Administrador**: Se o seu objetivo é acessar com privilégios de administrador, você deve ter uma conta de administrador ou superusuário configurada no sistema. Em sistemas de gerenciamento de banco de dados como o Oracle, isso envolve ter a função ou perfil adequado.
3. **Recuperação de Senha**: Se você acha que a senha está incorreta ou esqueceu a senha de administrador, verifique se há opções de recuperação de senha ou redefinição disponíveis.
4. **Permissões e Papéis**: Em alguns sistemas, mesmo que você tenha uma conta de administrador, talvez precise ajustar as permissões ou atribuições de papéis para garantir que tenha acesso total.
5. **Configurações de Conexão**: Verifique se você está fornecendo as configurações de conexão corretas, como nome do servidor, porta e outros detalhes relevantes.
6. **Depuração**: Se você estiver enfrentando problemas persistentes de autenticação, verifique os logs de erro ou mensagens de erro que o sistema está fornecendo. Eles podem conter pistas sobre o que está acontecendo.

Se você está tentando acessar um sistema específico, como o Oracle SQL Developer, sugiro consultar a documentação do sistema ou entrar em contato com o suporte técnico para obter assistência específica. Cada sistema pode ter suas próprias configurações e procedimentos de autenticação.
O erro ORA-01932 indica que você está tentando conceder ou atribuir um privilégio que requer a opção ADMIN a um usuário ou função, mas você não possui essa opção. Isso geralmente acontece com certos privilégios, como o privilégio de administrador (sysdba) ou privilégios de certos papéis especiais.

Vamos analisar o seu exemplo de comandos:

1. `GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO ****;`
2. `GRANT ALL TO ****;`

No primeiro comando, você está tentando conceder os privilégios CONNECT e RESOURCE a um usuário ou função. No entanto, o erro menciona que a opção ADMIN não foi concedida para a atribuição 'CONNECT', o que indica que você não tem permissão para conceder esses privilégios diretamente.

No segundo comando, você está tentando conceder todos os privilégios a um usuário ou função, mas novamente você não tem a opção ADMIN necessária para fazer isso.

Para resolver esse problema, você pode precisar seguir estas etapas:

1. Verifique suas próprias permissões: Certifique-se de que você tenha a permissão necessária para conceder esses privilégios. Você pode precisar de privilégios administrativos, como DBA, para conceder determinados privilégios a outros usuários.
2. Conceda os privilégios necessários a si mesmo: Se você for o administrador do sistema, certifique-se de que possui os privilégios apropriados para conceder esses privilégios aos outros.
3. Use uma conta com privilégios apropriados: Se você não possui os privilégios necessários, considere usar uma conta com privilégios administrativos, como um usuário com a função DBA.
4. Revise os privilégios requeridos: Verifique a documentação do Oracle ou consulte um administrador de banco de dados para determinar quais privilégios específicos são necessários para conceder CONNECT, RESOURCE ou outros privilégios semelhantes.

Lembre-se de que a concessão de privilégios é uma ação sensível que requer cuidado, pois pode afetar a segurança e a integridade do sistema de banco de dados. Certifique-se de entender completamente os privilégios que está concedendo e os requisitos para fazê-lo.